# Why change event of an input does not fire with jQuery?

Tags: input, jquery, onchange

I use jQuery with asp.net.
I have an Input that its value will change after a process:
first a button is clicked and a popup dialog is opened and an item is selected, then popup is closed and the value of my input is changed.
i want to get the change event and do sth, but nothing happen.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the popup is opened I set the parameter in session and then when the main page is focused I checked if the session has value (with ajax) and then I got the change value!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/rsarika/b9NTS/1/